# When, if necessary, do I need to close my connection to APNs?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am writing code to support APNs communication on a server. I am anticipating push notifications to be triggered frequently. Is there ever a reason I should intentionally close my connection with APNs and reopen later? e.g. If there happens to be ~1 minute break between any notification.